# Mock cookies attribute of requests.session

Tags: python, mocking, python-requests

`Session.cookies` is defined inside the Session constructor and thus I can't mock it. Is there any way to mock it?

```
from requests import Session
from settings import URL
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch.object(Session, 'cookies', new='my custom mock object')
def test_request():
    assert function_that_uses_request_cookies()
```

This raises `AttributeError: <class 'requests.sessions.Session'> does not have the attribute 'cookies'`

If `session` instance was defined on the module scope, I could patch the `session` instance directly. But `session` is defined only on `function_that_uses_request_cookies` scope. Is there any way to patch the instance inside the function scope?

Comment: None of your own code is invoked in that test. What are you trying to test? If you want to mock out requests for testing your own code, try [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses).

Comment: The point is not what I'm trying to test, but how to mock this attribute that is defined inside the class constructor.

Comment: You can mock the cookiejar constructor: `@patch('requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar', ...`  But...  Not sure what you want to do after that.

Comment: Well if you mock the Session instance, you can set whatever attributes on it you like. If you're not mocking it, you probably shouldn't be patching out random bits of it. But it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve, so this is probably an http://xyproblem.info.

Comment: Just updated the code. Maybe it's clearer now. How can I mock cookies instance? it's being created inside that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the code will patch an attribute of the `Session` class, but what you want to do is patch an attribute of a `Session` instance. To do this without interrupting other aspects of session behaviour, you can create a mock object that wraps `Session`.

```py
def test_request():
    mock_session_klass = MagicMock(wraps=Session)
    with patch('requests.Session', new=mock_session_klass):
        session_instance = mock_session_klass.return_value
        session_instance.cookies.return_value = 'my custom mock object'
        assert function_that_uses_request_cookies()
```